# Office.js Beta release - How to create a sunburst chart

Tags: office-js

The beta release indicates new charts are supported  : "Explore our new supported chart types: maps, box and whisker, waterfall, sunburst, pareto and funnel"

I would like an example of how to create a new sunburst chart with the chart object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
async function createSunburstChart() {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      await OfficeHelpers.ExcelUtilities.forceCreateSheet(context.workbook, "Sunburst");
      let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sunburst");
      sheet.activate();
      sheet.showGridlines = false;
      //const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

      // prepare table data for waterfall chart
      // let expensesTable = sheet.tables.getItemOrNullObject("sunburst");
      // expensesTable.load("name");
      // await context.sync();
      // if (expensesTable.name == null)
      // {
      let expensesTable = sheet.tables.add("A1:C1", true);
      expensesTable.name = "sunburst";
      expensesTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [["Category", "Sub-Category", "Sales"]];

      expensesTable.rows.add(null, [
        ["Furniture", "Furnishings", 560.32],
        ["", "Tables", 3123.518],
        ["", "Bookcases", 66.586],
        ["", "Furnishings", 560.32],
        ["", "Chairs", 1427.22],
        ["Office Supplies", "Storage", 902.28],
        ["", "Art", 306.776],
        ["", "Labels", 100.714],
        ["", "Paper", 255.806],
        ["", "Fasteners", 33.776],
        ["", "Binders", 236.668],
        ["", "Envelopes", 128.578],
        ["", "Appliances", 917.702],
        ["", "Supplies", 32.992],
        ["Technology", "Accessories", 1532.03],
        ["", "Phones", 3949.406],
        ["", "Accessories", 1532.03],
        ["", "Machines", 0]
      ]);
      // }

      //end of prepare table data for waterfall chart

      let bwRange = sheet.getRange("A1:C19");

      //let chart = sheet.charts.getItemOrNullObject("sunburst");
      // chart.load("name");
      // await context.sync();
      // if (chart.name == null) {
      let chart = sheet.charts.add("Sunburst", bwRange, "auto");
      chart.setPosition("E2:L19");
      chart.name = "sunburst";
      //}
      chart.series.getItemAt(0).hasDataLabels = true;
      await context.sync();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
    OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this out and get : Exception was thrown at line 24, column 277936 in https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.  I am referencing "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js"  . Not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: can you please share your Office Build? what version of Office you are running? you need to update to latest to try this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I upgraded the office build to latest and it worked.